# Collision detection in html5 canvas between two squares

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
class Snake {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 400;
        this.y = 400;
        this.width = 25;
        this.height = 25;
    }
    
    draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
let snake = new Snake();

class Food {
    constructor() {
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 0) + 0)
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 0) + 0)
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
/*         this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = 'img/apple.png' */
    }
    update() {
    } 
    draw() {
/*         ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height); */
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

    }
}
let food = new Food() 
function collision(){
    if(snake.x < food.x + food.width &&
        snake.x + snake.width > food.x &&
        snake.y < food.y + food.height  &&
        snake.height + snake.y > food.y){
            alert("hit")

        } 
}
collision()
```

I have two JS classes one portrays a snake the other portrays food, I tried this collision algorithm I found but it's not working. where is my mistake or how can I make the collision happen?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to call collision() in the animate function

```js
function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    snake.draw();
    snake.update();
    food.draw()
    collision()

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```